# Column editing in Notepad++ is awesome. How can I copy/paste in column mode?

Tags: notepad++

Let's say I have a document like this:

> A
>
> A
>
> A
>
> B
>
> B
>
> B

How can I put the Bs after the As on each line, like this:

> A B
>
> A B
>
> A B

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's simple:

1. Hold the Alt key and select the B lines as columns
2. Cut or Copy the selection (Ctrl-x or Ctrl-c)
3. Hold Alt and select the column to the right of the As
4. Paste (Ctrl-v)

Comment: It didn't work pressing ctrl+c, but then I hovered over Edit , over paste option and it worked

Comment: @Theta30 What are you talking about? You cannot hover over anything when you hold the Alt pressed!

Comment: @Val you can hover if you keep on your finger over the left click-works better with a mouse

Comment: Exactly what I need to do too. I did steps 1 to 3 above but when I paste in step 4 only the line is merged properly (with A followed by B). All remaining B text is appended behind the bottommost A line.