# Need File Adjustement

Tags: notepad++

I have a a huge txt file that looks like this:

```
1 
2
3
4
Générateur De Code PSN Gratuit – 2014 – PSN Codes Gratuit.rar
Générateur de code Starpass et Allopass 2014.rar
Generateur De Code Starpass v1.12.rar
Générateur de Microsoft Points Gratuit 2014.rar
```

Is there any way (using NPP for ex.) to make it look like this:

```
1 Générateur De Code PSN Gratuit – 2014 – PSN Codes Gratuit.rar
2 Générateur de code Starpass et Allopass 2014.rar
3 Generateur De Code Starpass v1.12.rar
4 Générateur de Microsoft Points Gratuit 2014.rar
```

Comment: You could try modifying this [How to merge lines every 3 rows in Notepad++?](http://superuser.com/questions/678046/how-to-merge-lines-every-3-rows-in-notepad)

Comment: @MC10 My txt file has 776 rows of numbers & below them 776 rows of phrases so I need a quick method not just divide it by 3

Comment: Duplicate of [Column editing in Notepad++ is awesome. How can I copy/paste in column mode?](http://superuser.com/q/555819)